# How to make addItem function in QComboBox to add last Item in the first positionfist

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, reverse, qcombobox

I have a Stopwatch programm. And I need to see all the lap times in the order: the last should be the first. I have QComboBox:

```
self.lap_times_combo.addItem(f'{hh1:02d}:{mm1:02d}:{ss1:05.2f}')
```

It works all right. But it shows the laps in order from very first to very last.

How to revers it so I should see the last lap clocked in the window and if I click on ComboBox I should see all the laps last to first order ?
In other words how to make addItem to add items always in [0] position ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is not to use [`addItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#addItem) but to insert the item to the first position using the [`insertItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#insertItem) method:

```py
self.lap_times_combo.insertItem(0, f'{hh1:02d}:{mm1:02d}:{ss1:05.2f}')
```